# How to make Apk of Xamarin Application to Run on Android Device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin Mobile App Development.I have developed a basic mobile app but I am having an issue with creating the `.apk` to test it on my Samsung Galaxy S-5 Android phone.I searched few ways from google but None of them worked. Kindly suggest some simple solution for this, also I want to run the app on windows phone too if there is any way for that as well?.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: is your problem creating the APK file, or installing it on your phone?  Please be more specific about the problem you're having

Comment: You must create a Xamarin Forms app if you want cross compatibility

Comment: I am having issue in creating .apk file @jason

Answer (score 3):

For Generating an APK file you need to perform the following steps in Visual Studio 15:

1.In your toolbar change the project from debug mode to release mode

2.Right-click on your Project and Select Archive...

3.Click on the generated archive and below on the Right side you will find two options Open folder and Distribute. (Select Distribute)

4.Then on the Pop-up that appears Select AD-HOC

5.Click on the Green plus icon to add signing identity where you need to provide the identity of the signing person or company

6.After creating the signing identity click on that identity to select it and then click on save as to save your APK.

7.A pop-up will appear asking password for the signing identity which you will produce in step 5.

And The same project cannot run on windows phone unless you are using Xamarin forms, so I would suggest you that you create future projects in Xamarin forms so you can access the cross-platform feature that Xamarin is well known for.

Goodluck!