# testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop

Recently I have implemented firebase in my Xamarin Android project.
After that it is working successfully in Debug mode,but when i go to release mode,
application is getting installed but crashes on opening.
I saw the Device log,saw some error saying-

testDefaultGrantsWithRemoteExceptions:android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.permission.gts

I am not sure whether it is related to firebase or something else.
Just visited the link-
https://sunj.iteye.com/blog/2387714

How can i do this in Xamarin.Android where this method can be implemented,
also how will it effect application.

Also is there any way to see the reason why application is crashing,there is no error ,no exception.In output window also nothing weird showing,but still crashes in Release mode.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure but  this could be a solution to your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299793/7462031

Comment: And adding some firebase related code would be a good thing!

Comment: Just now found something new...its saying crashlyticsprovider:class not found error.Somewhere I saw if we use proguard with firebase..problems like this will arise...I am still looking for solution

Comment: What are you using firebase for? is it push notifications? or analytics? and are you using progaurd?

Comment: @G.hakim Its normal firebase code,nothing complex

Comment: @G.hakim-Firebase Analytics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188791/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-uncle-scrooge).